# Indexing Method Results in ElasticSearch from Associated ActiveRecord Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, acts-as-taggable-on

I am following the example here for indexing ActiveRecord objects and associated objects in Elasticsearch.
https://gist.github.com/karmi/3200212

Is there anything else that I would need to take into account if the associated object is storing the results of a method?  I'm actually using the acts-as-taggable-on gem with tag_list.  My to_indexed_json looks like this guy:

```
to_json(include: { items: {only: :name, methods: :tag_list} })
```

When I rebuild with the following,

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Business FORCE=true
```

it successfully included the results of tag_list for each Item.

Following the example, Business does a tire.update_index after being touched.
However, when I add a new "Item," it successfully adds all the attributes of said Item but without the tag_list.

Here's a link to my two models:  https://gist.github.com/grumpasuarus/6661414

Comment: can you paste your model file including the code for elastic search.

Comment: Updated the question with a link to the two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wasn't understanding how the to_json method worked with "methods: :tag_list".

In order for that to work, I needed a method "tag_list" at my Business model.

To ultimately resolve the issue, I created a method in the Business model to get me all the tagging information for given item.